# Java 8 LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime conversion

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdate, zoneddatetime

Given a zone name and the `outputDtf`, is this the best way to use Java 8 LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime? I would like to simplify where possible.

```
String zoneName = "America/Los_Angeles";
DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName));

// timestamp in UTC. convert to zone America/Los_Angeles
DateTimeFormatter timestampDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String timestamp = "20180722060602";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, timestampDtf);
Instant tsInstant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();
System.out.println(outputDtf.format(tsInstant));
// 2018-07-21T23:06:02-0700

// date in zone America/Los_Angeles. add start of day and zone
DateTimeFormatter dateDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = "2018-07-18";
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse(date, dateDtf).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName));
System.out.println(outputDtf.format(zdt));
// 2018-07-18T00:00:00-0700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than dropping the `toInstant()` in the first example, there is nothing to simplify.

You have to parse the input string, you have to specify the time zone, and for a date-only you have to say it's at midnight.

Those are the steps you're doing, and it cannot be simplified, though you can make the `DateTimeFormatter` do the work.

```
String zoneName = "America/Los_Angeles";
DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName));

// timestamp in UTC. convert to zone America/Los_Angeles
DateTimeFormatter timestampDtf = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String timestamp = "20180722060602";
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, timestampDtf);
System.out.println(outputDtf.format(zdt1)); // 2018-07-21T23:06:02-0700

// date in zone America/Los_Angeles. add start of day and zone
DateTimeFormatter dateDtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneId.of(zoneName));
String date = "2018-07-18";
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateDtf);
System.out.println(outputDtf.format(zdt2)); // 2018-07-18T00:00:00-0700
```

As you can see, if the `DateTimeFormatter` is set up once and re-used, the code *using* it is simpler, but overall the code is not simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is generally fine, there’s not much you can do better.

In the first snippet I would use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `Instant`:

```
    OffsetDateTime tsOffsetDateTime = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(outputDtf.format(tsOffsetDateTime));
```

You don’t need the formatter in the second snippet since your string, `2018-07-18`, is in the default format for `LocalDate` (AKA ISO 8601):

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.parse(date).atStartOfDay().atZone(zone);
```

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)